# Append or Add to string of specific index

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of class objects 'x'. I am trying to create a new list by appending certain attribute values of the objects but I would like to append more that one attribute per index. For example, what I currently get:

```
x = blah.values()

newList = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i].status == 'ACT':
        newList.append(str(x[i].full_name)),
        newList.append(str(x[i].team))
else:
    pass

print newList
```

The above code provides me with something like:

```
['Victor Cruz', 'NYG', 'Marcus Cromartie', 'SF',....]
```

What I am trying to get:

```
['Victor Cruz NYG', 'Marcus Cromartie SF',....]
```

How can I append more than one attribute per index? Hope this make sense, I can try to further elaborate if needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.format()` in order to format your string. Notice the space between `{} {}`

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i].status == 'ACT':
        newList.append("{} {}".format(x[i].full_name,x[i].team) )
```

Another way is using `"%s" % string` notation

```
newList.append("%s %s" % (str(x[i].full_name),str(x[i].team)))
```

Another example of `.format` using.

```
"{} is {}".format('My answer', 'good')
>>> "My answer is good"
```

Comment: Above suggestions appreciated! Both answers so far work perfect

Answer (score 2):

You could put the items into one string using `.format()` and `append` the string once:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i].status == 'ACT':
        newList.append('{} {}'.format(x[i].full_name, x[i].team))
```

---

On a lighter note, using a *list comprehension* is a great alternative for creating your list:

```
newList = ['{} {}'.format(o.full_name, o.team) for o in blah.values() if o.status == 'ACT']
```

You'll notice that `range` and `len` are no longer used in the comprehension, and there is no longer need for *indexing*.

Comment: Appreciated suggestion and explanation. Both solutions work!